# ListView button not always working

Tags: android

As you can see, i have a listview with textviews and a button pressing of which causes a phone call. The problem is that after selecting a list item ( which always works) pressing the button leads to weird behavior: sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. I have read similar topics but was unable to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated

```
for (i = 0; i < final_itinList.size(); i++) {
final_itinList.get(i).put("num", String.valueOf(i + 1));
String timi = final_itinList.get(i).get("diff");
final_itinList.get(i).put("diff", timi + "Km");
            }

final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
CheckItineraries.this, final_itinList,
R.layout.list_item2, new String[] { "num",
"startPoliPro", "finalPoliPro", "diff" },
new int[] { R.id.number_n, R.id.startpoli,
            R.id.finalpoli, R.id.numKm });


list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View container, int position, long id) {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position-1);
                    final String phone_number = (String) obj.get("phone_number");


 Button btnphone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnphone);
    btnphone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View btnphone) {

    try {                                               
            Intent intent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phone_number));
                                startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Demo application",
        "Failed to invoke call", e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things which not seems to be right in your code snippet using `ListView`. I would recommend to look into [Google I/O presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) for proper using `ListView` in android.

The problem in your code snippet that you're trying to bind the button action event on ListView row Item `onClick` event - which is completely wrong! You've to override the `getView` method of adapter and inflate the childview for each row item with provided dataset.

For example:

```
   public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResId;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, 
                    int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {

        super (context, data, resource, from, to);

        // hold the items
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResId = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderItem viewHolder;
        if (converView == null) {

             // inflate the layout
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
             convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResId, parent, false);

             // well set up the ViewHolder
             viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
             viewHolder.phoneBtn = (Button)view.findById(R.id.btnphone); 

             // store the holder with the view.
             convertView.setTag(viewHolder);    
        }
        else {
             // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
             // just use the viewHolder
             viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // Don't know the purpose of position-1 here.
        HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position-1);
        if (data != null) {

            String phone_number = (String)data.get("phone_number");

            // set button action
            viewHolder.phoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                  try {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                     intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_number));
                     startActivity(intent);
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                     Log.e("Demo application", "Failed to invoke call", e);
                  }
              }
           }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hold View items 
     */   
    static class ViewHolderItem {

        private Button phoneBtn;
    }
}
```

Now you can create the object of `CustomAdapter` and assign to ListView.

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(
                                    CheckItineraries.this, 
                                    final_itinList,
                                    R.layout.list_item2, 
                                    new String[] { "num", "startPoliPro", "finalPoliPro", "diff" },
                                    new int[] { R.id.number_n, R.id.startpoli, R.id.finalpoli, R.id.numKm });

// set the adapter
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Note**: The `ViewHolderItem` defined earlier is android design pattern that reduce the look-ups `findViewById()` and increase the performance for smooth scrolling. You can find more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a button listener inside an list item listener.

That means: when you click a list item, the button click listener is set. Only then can you click that specific button to invoke the call.

---

What you have to do is to create a custom adapter, that sets the **button listener** once the list item is inflated (created). Here's an example:

```
for (i = 0; i < final_itinList.size(); i++) {
    final_itinList.get(i).put("num", String.valueOf(i + 1));
    String timi = final_itinList.get(i).get("diff");
    final_itinList.get(i).put("diff", timi + "Km");
}

final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        CheckItineraries.this, final_itinList,
        R.layout.list_item2, new String[] { "num",
        "startPoliPro", "finalPoliPro", "diff" },
        new int[] { R.id.number_n, R.id.startpoli,
                R.id.finalpoli, R.id.numKm }) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Fetch the phone number (dunno why you have position-1...)
        HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position-1);
        final String phone_number = (String) obj.get("phone_number");
        Log.d("phone", phone_number);

        // Set the button click listener
        Button btnphone = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnphone);
        btnphone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View btnphone) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_number));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Demo application", "Failed to invoke call", e);
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
};
```

*Note:* This way of re-setting the button listener is inefficient, but nevertheless it should work (as long as your other code works). If you run into further problems you should ask another question.

Comment: I'm getting an error : " The local variable adapter may not have been initialized

Comment: @FeniaKechagia updated, you just need to remove `adapter` there.